# Android 11: change ownership of media_rw files

Tags: internal-sd, android-11, file-permissions, titanium-backup, termux

Could somebody please help with the following problem on ArrowOS, Android 11?

**Background**

I use **TitaniumBackup** to create regular app backups. The TiBu folder is on **internal storage**. Then, after that, I use **Tasker/Termux** and the `rsync` command to sync the TiBu folder (among others) to my **external SD card**.

**Problem**

I got **error messages when rsyncing**: some files were not transferred - **permission denied**. I found out that the problem is **file ownership** - the files that can be transferred are owned by `u0_211` which is the default storage app. however, those that cannot be transferred are owned by `media_rw`.

I have no idea if this is some new TiBu behavior or whether I messed something up. As far as I know, `media_rw` is the **default user for stuff on external SD**. So something must be wrong here. At any rate, I cannot change ownership of these files even as the root user.

**Question**

Is there any way I could change ownership of these files? Or maybe some other solution/ workaround?